# Visualize 3D polygon and TIN stored in postgis

Tags: postgis, 3d, visualisation

How can we visualize 3D polygon and TIN data stored in POSTGIS? My input is 3D mesh data generated by AR application. I have created polygon by adding all the vertices of an object. I can visualize my objects in the unity, but I want to visualize the data in the form I have stored in postgis. (mostly to verify that the I have stored it is correct) Also, while am running query like ST_Intersects I am getting wrong output based on the visualization in unity. I do not have shape files. I have also, tried viewing it using X3D viewer, by generating X3d file using ST_AsX3D from postgis, but didn't work.Please suggest any tool/ option to visualize this data.

Comment: Can you give an example of the "wrong output" you're getting?

Comment: I ran ST_Intersects with obj1, on my table with 58 rows, out of those I am getting obj1 intersects with obj5 and obj8 as intersecting, however in Unity obj1 is very far from obj5 and obj8. Other than this all True or False output were correct.